# "Content and structure" link shows error after migration from 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2016, migration, content-and-structure

I see a "Sorry Something went wrong" error when I open "Content and structure" page after migrating from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016. Below are the logs from hive.

> No windows identity for pitcairn\spfarm.
>
> 2eaa8617-8855-4cc9-a98c-0ebd13a2b3f9 Stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtWebEcbMenu.setupTypeSpecificMenu()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtEcbMenuFactory.CreateSmtEcbMenu(Control
>   ownerTreeView, ISmtPageControl smtPageControl, ObjectSerializer
>   treeViewObject, ObjectSerializer treeViewObjectParent, String
>   menuPrefix)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.SmtTreeNode.createEcbMenu(Control
>   ownerTreeView, ObjectSerializer treeViewObject, ObjectSerializer
>   treeViewObjectParent)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.EcbEnabledTreeNode.RenderPreText(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32
>   position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.RenderChildNodes(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, Int32 depth, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32
>   position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.RenderChildNodes(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, Int32 depth, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32
>   position, Boolean[] isLast, Boolean enabled)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   ASP._layouts_15_sitemanager_aspx.__RenderForm1(HtmlTextWriter __w,
>   Control parameterContainer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)      at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)

But prior to migrating from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 and that seems to be working fine and does not show any error when I open "Content and Structure" page.

Please let me know if anybody faced the issue.